# Twitter bootstrap responsive dropdown menu does not push down content in IE7-8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

When my collapsed drop down menu collapses, it pusshes the content down the page in FF & Chrome but in IE [even 9] it falls down over the content leaving it largely unreadable.

Comment: post code / fiddle so we can see

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the "overflow" css property, it sounds like it's handling it differently between the browsers.  Also, try looking int Developer Tools (shift - f12) in ie and see what css property ie is picking up or missing that the other browsers aren't.